# Python: Using Dataclass field value as input when assigning value to another field in same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from utils import get_debt, get_profits

@dataclass
class Company:
    name: str
    debt: int
    profits: int

companies = [
    Company(
        name="XYZ",
        debt=1020423,
        profits=94324314,
    ),
    Company(
        name="KRT",
        debt=get_debt("KRT"),
        profits=get_profits("KRT"),
    ),
    Company(
        name="TRH",
        debt=get_debt("TRH"),
        profits=get_profits("TRH"),
    )
]
```

I have a dataclass where I mostly get the value of the fields debt and profit using a function that takes name as input. Is there a smart way to avoid typing the name thrice?
get_debt(Position.name) does not work.

Comment: Why not just use a custom constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=__post_init__#post-init-processing) like so:

```
@dataclass
class Company:
    name: str
    debt: float | None = None
    profits: float | None = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.debt is None:
            self.debt = get_debt(self.name)
        if self.profits is None:
            self.profits = get_profits(self.name)
```

Then simply not fill debt and profits:

```
Company(name="KRT")
```

Do I suggest doing it? Don't know. I usually prefer an anemic model, as `get_profits` and `get_debt` might change, thus composition has its advantages, but that's more of an architectural debate.

Comment: Or declare `debt: float = field(Init = False)`, and same for `profits`, and set them in `__post_init__`

Comment: @gimix but then I don't believe you'll be able to supply a custom value

Comment: yes, I imagined OP gets the data from an external service or something

Comment: @gimix see his example code. He "mostly" but not always uses a service.

Comment: This means the type has to be optional, which means the type checker yells that it might be None every time you access it, even though it's only None for the nonce between `__init__` and `__post_init_`.

Comment: @Jeff You don't really have much choice unless you want a different initvar. You get set debt to Nan but that's ugly